# Can open fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser- windows batch file

Tags: javafx, font-awesome

Can someone tell how to open font awesome font browser (linked below)- windows batch file.

when I double click, command is opening but it shows an exception and closing.

How can I know whats wrong even a documentation link would be very helpful?

https://github.com/Jerady/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser

thank you

Comment: Run the command from CMD so the window doesn't close when the process exits. Then paste the full [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) into your question (as formatted text) using the [edit] link.

Comment: can you explain what you meant by " Run the command from CMD " what should i run in the command..can you explain it little bit??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed it by dragging and dropping the fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser.file into cmd and hitting enter that showed the error which showed that my JAVA_HOME is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 1.0 version https://www.jensd.de/wordpress/?p=2498, the 1.3.0 version can't open.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too but solved it by updating java, I used javacpl.exe (you'll find it in the C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin or the location you installed your java in(the jre/bin folder) )
Then i updated my JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME path in environment variables with the updated jdk and jre folder location.
I then opened cmd and ran "java -version " to confirm that java was in path.
lastly i executed the "fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser.bat" file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Well i had this issue too and i fixed you go to the java Folder/ bin folder and search for jvm.dll (in my case i found jvm1.dll ) so you copy it and create a folder name it Server if you found it before just copy the jvm.dll in it if you find it jvm1.dll just rename it and magic happen ! hope that i helped you